# Why are there two sets of closing buttons for windows in the files application?

Tags: unity, launcher, display, themes, unity-tweak-tool

When I click on files in the Unity launcher There is a close/minimise/maximise buttons on both sides (top right and top left). Why is this? I tried to solve it using Unity launcher but that didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry. it says you must have 10 points to post screenshot

Comment: You can post a link.

Comment: Upload to imgur and add link here in comments

Comment: http://imgur.com/ddPK3kT

Comment: here i the link of image